# CSS Background Image Will NOT Show - Image In Same Folder

Tags: html, css, image, background, web

I've made a simple website with a navigation bar and a couple other things, and I've sectioned off the nav section with:

```
<div id="navBar"> nav stuff </div>
```

That's in my html document.
This is what's in the CSS file:

```
navBar { background-image:url(images/img1) no-repeat;
 width: 200px;
 height: 384;
 }
```

More information: ALL files are in the same directory, a file on my desktop. I've tried putting the image out by itself with the CSS file, putting it in a folder named images, image, imgs, img, etc. ... NOTHING is working...
Please help! This is getting to the point where I'm ready to give up on adding images.

PS:
- I've tried adding the image to other sections, such as the ul, li, and the a sections... nothing worked.

Comment: Typo? There's no navbar element, so it should be `#navBar`.

Comment: Also not sure if you put the image location in a single quote.

Comment: and the `url()` attribute takes a string, including the file extension, so it should be `url('images/img1.png')`, also your `height` needs to have a dimension, probably `px`

Comment: @SoumyaKumar & LcLk - The quotes in the URL are optional. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri

Comment: None of that made any difference whatsoever

Comment: I've tried it all... and literally nothing is working...

Comment: UPDATE: 
Here's an image of my screen to provide the most accurate description possible...
All help is extremely welcome and appreciated. 
Shown in the image is my folder containing my CSS and HTML documents, and then the documents themselves pulled up (HTML is left, CSS is right).

http://gyazo.com/2214a7872bd9a0153b3b8eb0bc52f2c5

Answer (score 2):

You're missing # to reference the id, the quotes around the image name, and the image extension. Should be like this:

```
#navBar {
 background-image:url('images/img1.jpg') no-repeat;
 width: 200px;
 height: 384px;
 }
```

Comment: You don't need quotes around the URL. You can use no quotes, single quotes, or double quotes; each option is valid.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that the png image I chose is behind my nav bar, which is vertical on the site. NOTHING so far is making any image show up

Comment: UPDATE: 
Here's an image of my screen to provide the most accurate description possible...
All help is extremely welcome and appreciated. 
Shown in the image is my folder containing my CSS and HTML documents, and then the documents themselves pulled up (HTML is left, CSS is right).

http://gyazo.com/2214a7872bd9a0153b3b8eb0bc52f2c5